# Functional equation problem; chain of functions

Tags: problem-solving, functional-equations

I have tried more than an hour but couldn't solve it, can somebody please give me a clue?

$$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$$

$$f(f(f(X)))+f(f(X))+X=3f(X).$$
Find $f(X)$

I know that $f(X)=X$ is a solution, and I know that the function being (obviously) injective might help, but that's all the useful stuff I could gather.

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a complete solution, I tried $f(x)=kx$, $k$ constant, $k\ne0$, which results in
$$(1 - 3 k + k^2 + k^3) x=0.$$
If valid for all $x$ then
$$1 - 3 k + k^2 + k^3=0 \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad k=\{1,-1-\sqrt{2},-1+\sqrt{2}\}.$$