# Solving functional equations using recursion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

If $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ such that $f(f(f(n)))+f(f(n))+n=3f(n) \; \forall \; n\in \mathbb N,$ Then Find $f$

**Solution Provided in book:**

Replace $n$ with $f(n)$ successively in parent functional equation $k$ times. We get

$\underbrace {fofof...of(n)}_\text{k+3 times }+\underbrace {fofof...of(n)}_\text{k+2 times }+\underbrace {fofof...of(n)}_\text{k times }=3 \underbrace {fofof...of(n)}_\text{k+1 times }$ $\cdots \cdots(1)$

Let $a_0=n$ for some fixed $n$ and $a_{k+1}=f(a_k) \; \forall \;k\geq 0$

**My doubt: How did he assume $a_0=n$ and How it became $a_{k+1}=f(a_k)$**

Please Help In this. I also checked for duplicate but i couldn't find it.

Also Any other way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: That line in the book solution is *defining* the sequence of numbers $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$. Nothing "serious" has happened yet, in the passage you provided.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303723/functional-equation-problem-chain-of-functions , same eqn, different domain and codomain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence goes like this:

$$ \{ n, f(n) , f \circ f(n)... \}$$

The action of 'composition' with $f$ generates the next element in the sequence. Note that we are **not** making **any assumptions** about the nature of $f$ when we say that the first element of the said sequence is $n$, so everything is still done in total generality.

Comment: Also one more doubt why author replaced $n$ by $f(n)$ $k$ times. we can get the result if we replace only one time. Isn't it?

Comment: The original equation reads,
$$ f_3 + f_2 + f_0= 3 f_1$$

But if you replace with k times, you ahve:

$$ f_{3+k} + f_{2+k} + f_k= 3f_{k+1}$$

Which is a more general identity and also a recurrence relation

Comment: If you only have the relation between certain terms (not general index) it's not really a currence relation and it doesn't tell you how to generate out higher terms in the sequence @mathophile

Comment: There is one good book I found for topic like this. It requires little knowledge on anlaysis but I am sure can help you Christopher G Smalls functional analysis

Comment: Did my answer and comments clears your doubt? @mathophile

Answer (score 2):

Both of these statements are just definitions, we define a new sequence $(a_i)_i$ with

$$ a_0 := n $$

and

$$ a_{k+1} = f(a_k)$$

This is a recursive definition of a sequence given by an anchor ($a_0$) and a recursion, so no assumptions have been made yet.